# Can consumer SSD over-provisioning improve performance?

Tags: linux, performance, ssd

While reading up on ways to improve SSD endurance, I came across an [Intel whitepaper](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/over-provisioning-nand-based-ssds-better-endurance-whitepaper.pdf) on the subject of SSD over-provisioning (limiting the host-adressable space on a drive or not including some of the adressable in an partition to leave it for the controller to manage incoming data, reducing write amplification and improving the drive's endurance).
Curiously, the paper also mentions that over-provisioning can improve random write performance. Eager to test this, I ran sysbench random write tests on a couple of different configurations on my 256GB Intel 545s SSD.

1. 256/256GB addressable (27.5 MiB/s random 4k write)
2. 200/256GB addressable (26.5 MiB/s random 4k write)
3. 256/256GB addressable, containing a 200GB partition (26.5 MiB/s random 4k write)
4. 256/256GB addressable, containing a 150GB partition (26.8 MiB/s random 4k write)

To my disappointment configurations 2-4 all performed marginally worse than the non-user-overprovisioned configuration. Why am I not seeing an increase in performance? Am I testing wrong, or can the difference be explained with client SSD firmware behaving differently from the data centre drives the Intel paper shows as example?

The tests were done on a Linux system with ext4 filesystem running

```
sysbench --test=fileio --file-total-size=64G --file-test-mode=rndwr --init-rng=on --max-time=300 --max-requests=0 run
```

The drive didn't contain anything but the files sysbench creates for testing.

Comment: What tool did you partition the drive with? Did you issue a TRIM command between tests?

Comment: The command I used was hdparm.

Comment: I didn't issue fstrim between runs, no.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Over-provisioning the drive is not going to make the drive any 'faster', in a normal sense. The advertised peak speeds will not increase. What it will do, however, is make the  SSD perform better in high-usage situations. The drive will perform closer to peak performance for a longer time. This is explained in the whitepaper you linked.

This will happen in two ways:

**Endurance**. Since less of the drive is used for storage, there is more free space to be recycled resulting in a longer life than a drive of the same provisioned space, but with less spare area. This is due to memory cells having a fixed amount of writes in their life.

**Write amplification**. SSD's work in blocks and pages, not sectors like a traditional hard drive. The SSD completes housekeeping tasks in the background such as shuffling around pages and clearing blocks before new data can be written. During this time, client operations are paused. More spare area results in less of this happening, therefore increasing performance.

To truly see the performance benefits of this setup, you would need to write much more data to the drive. Writing only 64GB of data to an SSD with 256GB or 200GB of addressable space will not show a difference as it will not exceed the allocated area of the drive.

Comment: Well, being benchmarked is a high usage scenario. And the way the paper explains it (in the beginning) is that less adressable area means fewer house-keeping tasks and therefore better random write performance. In the end it says it will only be the case if "100% LBA span is used, or if filesystem is applied to the whole addressable capacity of the drive" which describes a non-over-provisioned drive.

Comment: Or, I guess it's not 'high usage' as in ' high drive usage', but it's a high load scenario, which should be dependent on the aforementioned house-keeping task count.

Comment: But -however the paper puts it- the performance is clearly better on an over-provisioned drive, when 200GB is taken up. It also helps running the default 10s write burst instead of the longer 300s I was using, cause it shows the fluctuations in performance caused by the housekeeping.